# 3.11 Lab: Smallest number

Tags: python

> Write a program whose inputs are three integers, and whose output is the smallest of the three values.
>
> If the input is:
>
> ```
> 7
> 15
> 3
> ```
>
> The output is: `3`

This is the code I have come up with:

```
num1 = input()
num2 = input()
num3 = input()

if (num1 < num2):
    if (num1 < num3):
        smallest_num = num1
elif (num2 < num1):
    if (num2 < num3):
        smallest_num = num2
else:
    smallest_num = num3
print(smallest_num)
```

This code works for that input, however if you input "29, 6, 17" it returned no output with an error

```
NameError: name 'smallest_num' is not defined".
```

I have dinked around quite a bit and tried adding `smallest_num = min(num1, num2, num3)` however nothing has yielded a passing output.

Comment: You have no `else:` for the inner `if` statements. So what do you think will happen when `num1 < num2` and `num3 < num1`?

Comment: Do you know what `input()` returns - a string or an integer?

Comment: Look what happens.  `num1` is less than `num2`, so you take the first if.  But `num1` is not less than `num3`, so you exit without doing anything.  Why aren't you just doing `m = min(num1,num2,num3)`?

Comment: You may want to try your code out in this Visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/  And learn how to debug.

Comment: Why not use `min(a, b, c)`? They need to be ints.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not integers. You have to use `int()`.

Comment: @RandomDavis ahhh, I can't believe it was that easy. I got hung up thinking my inputs were fine and the issue was somewhere else in the code since I had previously returned a good output. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `input()` returns a string. So when you compare your variables, you're doing string comparisons instead of numerical comparisons. So, you need to convert your input to integers.

```py
num1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter num3: "))

print(min(num1, num2, num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I use C++, but it also looks like you didn't define smallest_num as a variable which could be the only problem.

```py
if (num1 < num2 and num1 < num3):
    small = num1
elif (num2 < num1 and num2 < num3): 
    small = num2
else:
    small = num3
print(small)
```

Comment: The issue is that `input()` returns strings, hence the comparison was a string comparison rather than numerical. String comparison in Python uses lexicographic order.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needed help on this one in the future. :)

Original question: Write a program whose inputs are three integers, and whose output is the smallest of the three values.

If the input is:

7
15
3
The output is: 3

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

if (num1 < num2 and num1 < num3):
    small = num1

elif (num2 < num1 and num2 < num3): 
    small = num2
else:
    small = num3
print(small)
```

Comment: Please check existing answers before posting yours to make sure your answer does not duplicate other answers and provides value to the thread. As currently written, you are repeating the information already posted by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

if (num1 <= num2 and num1 <= num3):
small = num1

elif (num2 <= num1 and num2 <= num3): 
small = num2
else:
small = num3
print(small)
```

Comment: Using the <= or >= accounts for any equal number input which will return correct answers for any input.

Answer (score -1):

I am currently doing this lab for my own homework, and one thing that is missing from their responses is the definition of the variable that specifies which of the three values is the lowest/minimum value: **lowest = min(num1, num2, num3)**

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

lowest = min(num1, num2, num3)

if num1 < num2 and num1 < num3:
    lowest = num1

elif num2 < num1 and num2 < num3:
    lowest = num2

elif num3 < num1 and num3 < num2:
    lowest = num3

print(lowest)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())

smallest_num = min(num1, num2, num3)
if (num1 < num2):
    if (num1 < num3):
        smallest_num = num1
elif (num2 < num1):
    if (num2 < num3):
        smallest_num = num2
elif (num3 < num2):
    if (num3 < num1):
        smallest_num = num3

print(smallest_num)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Why are you redefining `smallest_num`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).